# Does Ubuntu One follow symlinks if synchronizing a folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, symbolic-link

I've looked for this question and haven't gotten a reasonable answer yet. If I synchronize a folder will it synchronize a symlink? Will it process all the way through the link to all the files within that symlink?

Answer (score 10):

From the [Ubuntu One FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/AreSymHardLinksSupported):

> ## Does Ubuntu One support symlinks or hard links?
>
> No, Ubuntu One does not currently support symlinks or hard links. If you are running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS or higher you can synchronize folders within your home directory by right-clicking on them and selecting "Synchronize on Ubuntu One".

Comment: If Ubuntu One doesn't support symlinks then why is there still the "Synchronize this Folder" menu when I right click on a symlink?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: You can create the hard link in a different folder; afterwards move this newly created hard link to your Ubuntu One folder. I tried this in a terminal and it worked, so I guess you can also write a script and use it as a nautilus script.