# Is there a way to add individual files to Ubuntu One, not just directories?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

I have a lot of files in a lot of different places on my computer I would like to be able to access from Ubuntu1. I just don't want to add all the directories. Is there a way to add just one file from a directory to U1 without adding the whole directory -or could I persuade the code-wizards to make it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably create a link in your Ubuntu One folder that refers to the file in the other folder, if you want to avoid copying the file.

Comment: I don't think that will work: U1 will sync the link, not the referent.  But, you can do the opposite: put the file within a synced folder, and then add a symlink to it from the other location.

Comment: A hard link is a reference to the file. It's just a different name for it.

Comment: Oh, a hard link.  Yes, that will work, if the programs that update it, and U1 itself, always update it in place rather than renaming over it.

Answer (score 1):

Same question with the right answer here: 
[Does Ubuntu One follow symlinks if synchronizing a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29062/does-ubuntu-one-follow-symlinks-if-synchronizing-a-folder) 
in Ubuntu One v 2.0.0, soft links are ignored and hard links are treated unreliably (completely ignored for me, but some people have had success).

Answer (score 0):

Well... copying the file.. Why didn't I think of that, that might be a possible solution. I was thinking in lines of doing the same thing to files as you do to directories, to add them to U1. But if that's not possible copying might do the trick...

Comment: I see where you're going. That should be fairly easy to implement in the client, I think. The question is how often it will be useful. If you have real world use cases that'll be generally useful, then I think you should write a blueprint on launchpad.